# How to modify build notification template? How to add BuildUri value?

Tags: tfs

I have enabled build notification e-mails from the TFS 2010 (any build completes option, HTML format). Our notification e-mails contains following message body:

[image: Build notification body]

As you can see we are not using drop location so "Build Log Location" is empty.
This e-mail is not as useful as it can be. Including BuildUri hyperlink to show build summary on the TFS Project Portal can be very useful.

**Questions:** 
How can I modify this notification e-mail template? 
Is it possible to add BuildUri into the notification e-mail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the email templates in %PROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010\Application Tier\TFSJobAgent\Transforms and modify them the way you want. In this folder you'll find the build completion events xsl files.

The build events expose a Url property, which shows the hyperlink in the email. I don't know from the top of my head what this link would open to, but can you clarify in which client you want to see your build from this email, TFS Web Access or Visual Studio?

Comment: I want to see my build status on TFS Web Access

Comment: Is it possible to have project specific build notification e-mail templates for projects in the TFS project collection? Currently we have 30+ projects...

Answer (score 2):

In answer to the first question, I found this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552337.aspx

It describes where the files are, what security permissions you need to edit them, and the purpose of each of the files.  It specifically mentions Work Item email notification templates, but the same applies to Team Build notifications.